# Why isn't my icon button rendered but not visible?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create an 'iconbutton' using an image. But when I run it, the icon button is not visible at all. If you check whether an input has been made by adding another button, etc.

Something is occupying space on the app screen, but it is not visible.
There is no error on the IDE, and it takes up space to see if the image is printed well. But it's just not visible.

What should I do?

**App.js**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
    import { theme, lightTheme, darkTheme } from "./theme";
    import { StatusBar, Button, Switch, Image, Dimensions } from "react-native";
    import Input from "./components/Input";
    import MyButton from "./components/MyButton";
    import { images } from "./images";
    import IconButton from "./components/IconButton";
    import Task from "./components/Task";


    const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
      flex: 1;
      background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.background};
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    `;


    const Title = styled.Text`
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: 100;
      color: ${(props) => props.theme.text};
      align-self: center;
      margin: 0px 20px;
    `;

    const List = styled.ScrollView`
      flex: 1;
      width: ${({ width }) => width - 40}px;
    `;

    export default function App() {
      const [isDark, setIsDark] = useState(false);
      const _toggleSwitch = () => setIsDark(!isDark);
      const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState("");
      const width = Dimensions.get("window").width;

      const _addTask = () => {
        alert(`Add: ${newTask}`);
        setNewTask("");
      };

      const _handleTextChange = (text) => {
        setNewTask(text);
      };

      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
          <Container>
            <Switch value={isDark} onValueChange={_toggleSwitch} />
            <StatusBar
              barStyle="light-content"
              backgroundColor={theme.background}
            />
            <Title theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>TODO LIST</Title>
            <Input
              placeholder="+ Add a Task!!"
              theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme}
              value={newTask}
              onChangeText={_handleTextChange}
              onSubmitEditing={_addTask}
            />
           

            <IconButton type={images.uncompleted} />
            <IconButton type={images.completed} />
            <IconButton type={images.delete} />
            <IconButton type={images.update} />

            <MyButton title="Button" theme={isDark ? darkTheme : lightTheme} />
          </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

**IconButton.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { images } from "../images";
import { theme } from "../theme";

const Icon = styled.Image`
  tint-color: "#000000;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
`;

const IconButton = ({ type, onPressOut }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPressOut={onPressOut} style={styles.iconbutton}>
      <Image source={type} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  iconbutton: {
    margin: 10,
  },
});

export default IconButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `IconButton` component is a wrapper around `react-native-image`. [Note that](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)

> for network and data images, you will need to manually specify the dimensions of your image!

It seems that your images are stored locally in `../images`. Try to provide a `width` and `height` style attribute to your `Image` as follows.

```js
<Image source={type} style={{width: 30, height: 30}}/>
```

I am not sure about your styled `Icon` component since you are not using it at the moment in your code. Maybe it was intended for this purpose.

Comment: Oh, I didn't explicitly set the width and height!
I tried changing it as you answered, but it still takes up space, but I can't see it.
In my opinion, something is messed up with the ability to switch to dark mode.